# Python: Conditional elements in array

Tags: python, arrays, conditional-statements

A question from a complete Python novice.

I have a column array where I need to force certain values to zero depending on a conditional statement applied to another array. I have found two solutions, which both provide the correct answer. But they are both quite time consuming for the larger arrays I typically need (>1E6 elements) - also I suspect that it is poor programming technique. The two versions are:

```
from numpy import zeros,abs,multiply,array,reshape

def testA(y, f, FC1, FC2):
    c = zeros((len(f),1))
    for n in xrange(len(f)):
        if abs(f[n,0]) >= FC1 and abs(f[n,0]) <= FC2:
            c[n,0] = 1.
    w = multiply(c,y)
    return w

def testB(y, f, FC1, FC2):
    z = [(abs(f[n,0])>=FC1 and abs(f[n,0])<=FC2) for n in xrange(len(f))]
    z = multiply(array(z,dtype=float).reshape(len(f),1), y)
    return z
```

The input arrays are column arrays as this matches the post processing to be done. The test can be done like:

```
>>> from numpy.random import normal as randn
>>> fs, N = 1.E3, 2**22
>>> f = fs/N*arange(N).reshape((N,1))
>>> x = randn(size=(N,1))
>>> w1 = testA(x,f,200.,550.)
>>> z1 = testB(x,f,200.,550.)
```

On my laptop **testA** takes 18.7 seconds and **testB** takes 19.3 - both for N=2**22. In **testB** I also tried to include "z = [None]*len(f)" to preallocate as suggested in another thread but this doesn't really make any difference.

I have two questions, which I hope to have the same answer:

1. What is the "correct" Python solution to this problem?
2. Is there anything I can do to get the answer faster?

I have deliberately not used any time at all using compiled Python for example - I wanted to have some working code first. Hopefully also something, which is good Python style. I hope to be able to get the execution time for N=2**22 below two seconds or so. This particular operation will be used many times so the execution time does matter.

I apologize in advance if the question is stupid - I haven't been able to find an answer in the overwhelming amount of not always easily accessible Python documentation or in another thread.

Comment: Is it required to use arrays for y, f and return value? Why not using lists instead?

Comment: In the following processing I need to do a bunch of matrix operations and I expected it to be the easiest (and what a user of the code would expect) to stay with the arrays. But if lists are better I could perhaps just transfer to arrays later.

Comment: The proposal by HYRY works great. It shaved time to below 0.4 seconds on my laptop. I am perfectly happy with this. Thanks a lot for the help! It is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use bool array to access elements in array y:

```
def testC(y, f, FC1, FC2):
    f2 = abs(f)
    idx = (f2>=FC1) & (f2<=FC2)
    y[~idx] = 0
    return y
```

Comment: Yes, that I also modified. But it really makes a huge difference - still easy to read and it performs very well indeed. Thanks for all your comments and help!

Comment: +1: That's the standard, efficient NumPy way, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are slower than HYRY solution by a large factor:

How about

`( x[1] if FC1<=abs(x[0])<=FC2 else 0 for x in itertools.izip(f,x)  )`

If you need to do random access (very slow)

`[ x[1] if FC1<=abs(x[0])<=FC2 else 0 for x in itertools.izip(f,x) ]`

or you can also use map

`map(lambda x: x[1] if FC1<=abs(x[0])<=FC2 else 0 , itertools,izip(f,x))`

or using vectorize (faster than A and B but much much slower than C)

```
b1v = np.vectorize(lambda a,b: a if 200<=abs(b)<=550 else 0)
b1 = b1v(f,x)
```

Comment: NumPy functions are usually *way* faster than standard Python functions, on arrays.  So, while this works, this does not fit perfectly with the "large array" part of the question.

Comment: Isn't map essentially doing the same as the second one you propose? I got the impression that map is essentially a generated list. But I could easily have misunderstood this.

Comment: Is this equivalent of map for numpy? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html

Comment: Ah.. I tested them including using vectorize. HYRY version is way faster.