# Using arrays in an if statement condition

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

How do I use arrays in the condition part of an `if` statement? I want the program to check every element's absolute value, and return the appropriate part. This gave some hope: [Function of Numpy Array with if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036878/function-of-numpy-array-with-if-statement)
But this technique isn't working in my case.
Here is the code I'm trying:

```
    def v(x,y):
        if x[abs(x)<a] and y[abs(y)<a]: 
            return #something 1
        if x[a<abs(x)<b] and y[a<abs(y)<b]:
            return #something 2
        if x[b<abs(x)<R] and y[b<abs(y)<R]:
            return #something 3
```

Here, x and y are arrays. (Actually a grid created by `x,y = ogrid[-R:R:.01, -R:R:.01]`)

Edit: The best way I found (after much trial and error) is to use boolean arrays. Here's the code:

```
    #Create a grid of coordinates. XY-Plane.
    x,y=ogrid[-R:R+1:1,-R:R+1:1] 

    #Create the polar distance 2D array. Conditions are tested on this array.    
    r=sqrt(x**2+y**2)     

    #Create 2D array to hold the result
    v=zeros([len(x*y),len(x*y)],float)

    #idr is the boolean 2D array of same size and shape as r. 
    #It holds truth values wherever the condition is true.
    idr=(r<a)
    v[~invert(idr)]= #function 1 of r[~invert(idr)]

    idr=((r>=a)&(r<b))
    v[~invert(idr)]= #function 2 of r[~invert(idr)]

    idr=(r>=b)&(r<=R)
    v[~invert(idr)]= #function 3 of r[~invert(idr)]

    print v
```

The values in v get updated at the correct locations.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: *isn't working* - do you get an exception? If so, please post the full exception and stack trace. Incorrect results? If so, what were you expecting? What did you get? If you want people to answer, you should also give a complete example - including some test data with expected output. That makes it much easier for people to help.

Comment: Emphasizing the fact that x and y are not lists. I need the 2D grid to make a contour plot.

Comment: What is `x[abs(x)<a]` supposed to mean? `x[True]`?

Comment: I get the usual error: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Comment: @PromitMoitra 'not lists' isn't particularly helpful. Are they `numpy.array()`s?

Comment: @PromitMoitra Please don't just tell us the text of the exception. Post the **full exception with the stack trace**. It's really not helpful to just not provide information that you have easy access to, that makes it *much* easier to diagnose the bug.

Comment: I need the program to check if the abs of each element of the array satisfies the given inequality.

Comment: yes. `numpy.array()`. and the error message is: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @PromitMoitra The stack trace is an important part of the exception. It tells us where and why the exception happened. Please add it to the question with an edit.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry, I'm new to programming and I don't know what you mean by a stack trace. Can you explain?

Comment: @PromitMoitra When an exception is thrown, Python gives you a long list of each call up to the one where the exception is thrown. It'll begin with `Traceback (most recent call last):`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 487, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Trials\untitled5.py", line 22, in <module>
    V=pot(x,y)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Trials\untitled5.py", line 14, in pot
    if x[x>-a and x<a] and y[y>-a and y<a]: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: @PromitMoitra Please edit your question to include it, as comments don't provide good formatting, and it's an important part of the question.

Comment: Have you looked at using [`all()`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-147db17da53bc378c2f3f90d4f65f97f1bc6194c)? It sounds like exactly what you need.

Comment: Please don't add an answer to your question. If you find a solution that wasn't given by one of the answers, please answer yourself. If it was given by an answer, just accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`all()`](http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#head-147db17da53bc378c2f3f90d4f65f97f1bc6194c), like in this:

```
import numpy

a = numpy.array([-1, -2, 1, 2, 3])
print(numpy.all(a > 0))
print(numpy.all(abs(a) > 0))
```

You get:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\XXX\Desktop>python test.py
False
True
```

So your first if statement would turn into this (assuming you have `import numpy`):

```
if numpy.all(abs(x) < a) and numpy.all(abs(y) < a): 
    return #something 1
```

Comment: Be careful not to mix up `numpy.all()` and the `all()` built-in.

Comment: @Lattyware Whoops! Good catch

Comment: Thank you! This also looks helpful, though I'm not sure how to use it:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594204/python-conditional-elements-in-array?rq=1

Answer (score -2):

If you wish to check the abslute value of every element, try this:

```
if( abs(x[1]) >= 3) #or whatever you want to check
if( abs(x[2]) >= 4) #or whatever
```

If x is an array that you are checking.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the asker does an `if` statement for every element of the array manually? -1

Comment: Well, that seems to be what he asked for, he stated "I want the program to check every element's absolute value" so that's what I thought he wanted.

Comment: You have given a way to check specific elements, not every element.